# Convert single element array to string with dot added before the string in Perl

Tags: arrays, string, perl

I have an array which has one element

I am trying to convert that array element to a string with a dot added before the string

```
my $string = [ 'text' ];

my $convert_str = join(".", @$string);

print $convert_str;
```

The expected output should be

```
.text
```

I am getting the output without dot as just:

```
text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Perl myself so sorry in advance if I got something wrong.

Using join would only "work" with arrays of 2 or more elements and the separator would be inserted in between the elements. For example

```pl
my $string = [ 'text', 'another' ];
my $convert_str = join(".", @$string);
print $convert_str;
```

would give the result `text.another`

If you only have 1 elements in the array and you want to prepend a dot before it then this could be done as follows

```pl
my $string = [ 'text' ];
my $convert_str = "." . $string->[0];
print $convert_str;
```

Here, I'm using `$string->[0]` to access the first element of the array and `.` to concatenate the dot and place it in front of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation for `join()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join) says this:

> **join EXPR,LIST**
> Joins the separate strings of LIST into a single string with fields separated by the value of EXPR, and returns that new string.

So you need to pass it a list of strings and it inserts the EXPR in between the elements of the list. You have a list with one item, so there's nowhere for the EXPR to go and your string is unchanged.

You can just prepend your dot by adding the dot to the string.

```
my $convert_str = ".$string->[0]";

print $convert_str;
```